# DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit doesn't work on WP Silverlight 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit doesn't work on WP Silverlight 8.1 app, it always return 0, do you know why? and is there have new replaceable API for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly it will return 0 as mentioned by this msdn link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationmemoryusagelimit(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationmemoryusagelimit%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

See the Caution section. the new api for this is MemoryManager. see the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.system.memorymanager.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you! MemoryManager is ok.